# Prevent LinkUI from closing while another modal is open

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I'm adding a browse button (highlighted in green) to the existing LinkUI plugin to be able to open a secondary modal to input a Link URL via a selection in the modal:
[image]

The modal opens fine:
[image: modal opened]

However once I click within the modal, as a click has occurred outside of the LinkUI, the LinkUI view will close:
[image: click outside closes the LinkUI view]

I see LinkUI uses the method `clickoutsidehandler` to close the LinkUI. I'm wondering if there's a way to temporarily disable this while my secondary modal is open.

Alternatively is there another approach?

I've tried to access disable the `activator` used by `clickoutsidehandler` but this does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a function as an argument for `contextElements` that returns all visible balloons, e.g.:

```
clickOutsideHandler({
  emitter: formView,
  activator: () => this._balloon.visibleView === formView,
  contextElements: () => [
    <HTMLElement>this._balloon.view.element,
    ...[].slice.call(
      document.querySelectorAll('.ck-balloon-panel_visible')
    ),
  ],
  callback: () => this._hideUI(),
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, in this instance I just added a check within `_hideUI` and returned out of the function if the secondary modal was open.